# Jasper report comparing dates at image expression not working

Tags: jasper-reports

How to compare dates in *JasperReports*?

I want to use the "image Expression". I tried but thats not working

```
$P{current_date} <= $P{image_date} ? '1.jpg' : '2.jpg'
 $P{current_date}.after($P{image_date}) ? '1.jpg' : '2.jpg'
new Long($P{current_date}.getTime()) <= new Long($P{image_date}.getTime()) ? '1.jpg' : '2.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have these parameters `class="java.util.Date"`

```
<parameter name="current_date" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="image_date" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

This image expression will work

```
 <image>
    <reportElement x="139" y="13" width="223" height="93" uuid="fdb46643-77b6-4d23-a88c-7108b97c091f"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{current_date}.after($P{image_date}) ? "Full absolute path\\1.jpg" :"Full absolute path\\2.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

I think that your problem is merly that you are giving **relative path** of image to jasper report... you need to give **absolute path** to jasper report es.  `"C:\\Users\\Friberg\\Pictures\\1.jpg"`

I also see some single `'` in your code you need to use the `"` to return the String value of your path.

*Development note: the 2 `\\` in the path is because `\` is escape char in java*